# SecurityException: Permission Denial: isUidActive from pid=XXXX, uid=XXXX requires android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS

Tags: android, nfc, android-permissions, permission-denied, android-securityexception

I'm getting this (for me) unknown crash in my crashlytics log trying to call `enableReaderMode()` in NfcAdapter class:

```
Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: isUidActive from pid=XXXX, uid=XXXX requires android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS
   at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2387)
   at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2371)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2354)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2296)
   at android.nfc.INfcAdapter$Stub$Proxy.setReaderMode(INfcAdapter.java:1027)
   at android.nfc.NfcActivityManager.setReaderMode(NfcActivityManager.java:242)
   at android.nfc.NfcActivityManager.enableReaderMode(NfcActivityManager.java:218)
   at android.nfc.NfcAdapter.enableReaderMode(NfcAdapter.java:1580)
   at com.my.package.enableNfc(MyClass.kt:23)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at androidx.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache$MethodReference.invokeCallback(ClassesInfoCache.java:216)
   at androidx.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache$CallbackInfo.invokeMethodsForEvent(ClassesInfoCache.java:194)
   at androidx.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache$CallbackInfo.invokeCallbacks(ClassesInfoCache.java:185)
   at androidx.lifecycle.ReflectiveGenericLifecycleObserver.onStateChanged(ReflectiveGenericLifecycleObserver.java:37)
   at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:361)
   at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:300)
   at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:339)
   at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:145)
   at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:131)
   at androidx.lifecycle.ReportFragment.dispatch(ReportFragment.java:68)
   at androidx.lifecycle.ReportFragment$LifecycleCallbacks.onActivityPostResumed(ReportFragment.java:188)
   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityPostResumed(Activity.java:1469)
   at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:8265)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4714)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4756)
   at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2296)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:239)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8071)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:626)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1015)
```

I'm initialzing my NfcAdapter by lazy, like this:

```
    private val nfcAdapter: NfcAdapter? by lazy {
    NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(activity)
}
```

And handling it in that way:

```
fun enableNfc() {
    nfcAdapter?.enableReaderMode(
        activity, callback,
        NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A or
            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_B or
            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_F or
            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_V or
            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_BARCODE,
        Bundle().apply {
            putInt(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_READER_PRESENCE_CHECK_DELAY, 250)
        }
    )
}
```

All devices I've tested run successfully, even those that don't have NFC available (which this feature is never triggered).

My question is: Which sort of permission should I grant besides `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />` in manifest file? Is it a runtime permission? **Why is triggering this exception related to stats ‍♂️?** It's happening in an Android 11 device

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, do you find any solution for this issue?

Comment: I've posted an answer here, see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69522598/crash-securityexception-permission-denial-isuidactive-from-pid-xxxx-uid-xxx/69522896#69522896

Comment: @PutraNugraha not yet... 

Comment: @DanBaruch but I'm not using `PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS` in my project. This crash has only taken place in one specific device for an alone user. I'm pretty lost... 


Comment: Adding the PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS permission or requesting its approval is not an answer because it is not required for nfcReader to work. In my case, this failure occurs only for Vivo 1907, Vivo 1920 gadgets.