# Crash - SecurityException: Permission Denial: isUidActive from pid=XXXX, uid=XXXX requires android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm getting an unknown crash from Crashlytics which triggered on calling `enableReaderMode()` in `NfcAdapter`

```
Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: isUidActive from pid=5xx1, uid=1xx7 requires android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS
       at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2387)
       at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2371)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2354)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2296)
       at android.nfc.INfcAdapter$Stub$Proxy.setReaderMode(INfcAdapter.java:1027)
       at android.nfc.NfcActivityManager.setReaderMode(NfcActivityManager.java:242)
       at android.nfc.NfcActivityManager.enableReaderMode(NfcActivityManager.java:218)
       at android.nfc.NfcAdapter.enableReaderMode(NfcAdapter.java:1580)
```

I was calling the `NfcAdapter.enableReaderMode()` in Activity `onResume()` as can be seen in the following

[image]

I have added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />` permission as well

Is there any other permission required to prevent these crash from occurring?
Or is there should anything to check before calling `NfcAdapter.enableReaderMode()`?

I also saw someone posted about these question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69204254/securityexception-permission-denial-isuidactive-from-pid-xxxx-uid-xxxx-requir), but it seems there yet any answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that, special permissions that are granted by the user in the system settings (usage stats access, notification access, …) are handled by `AppOpsManager`, which was added in Android 4.4. Therefore, I'm adding an extra check as follows

```kotlin
val mode = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        (getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE) as AppOpsManager).unsafeCheckOpNoThrow(
            AppOpsManager.OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS,
            Process.myUid(),
            packageName
        )
    } else null

val granted = if (mode != null && mode != AppOpsManager.MODE_DEFAULT) {
       mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED
    } else {
       checkCallingOrSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it's requesting that but there is such permission:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

You can check if your app has it by calling:

```
 public static boolean checkForUsagePermission(Context context) {
        @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
        UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) context.getSystemService("usagestats");
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000 * 1000, time).size() > 0;
    }
```

And, of course, you can request it by:

```
            Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
            startActivityForResult(settingsIntent, REQUEST_STATS_USAGE);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, seems by adding `PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS` in manifest, it requires an extra permission from the user to allow the usage stats from system settings, right? Therefore, by default, I always got `false` from `checkForUsagePermission()`

Comment: That's very weird, I'm on Android 11 and using this function and it's working properly

Comment: Hmm, well, Im testing on Android 10 though. Anyway, I use [these approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69564379/10467286) to check for the `PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS` permission. Will vote ur answer anyway, hopefully it may help for others